# How onclick and addEventListener handles toggling

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm creating a game played by two people where an active player changes on a button click. The 1st code only changed the activeplayer once in two clicks. When I rewrote the code into the 2nd one, the problem got solved.

1st

```
document.querySelector('.switchPlayer').addEventListener('click', function(){

   //switch current player
   currentPlayer === 1 ? currentPlayer = 2 : currentPlayer = 1;

};
```

2nd

```
document.querySelector('.switchPlayer').onclick = function(){

    //switch current player
    currentPlayer === 1 ? currentPlayer = 2 : currentPlayer = 1;
};
```

After googling, the only thing I could understand was that addEventListener can have multiple handlers as opposed to onclick which can have only one handler.

If anybody could teach me why the 2nd code works, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)

Comment: It's supposed to be `currentPlayer = currentPlayer === 1 ? 2 : 1;` or simply `currentPlayer = 3 - currentPlayer;` (also, original code seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/c7964Lwx/)

Comment: Do you only ever run this code once? Or do you run it repeatedly?

Comment: Side note: I'd strongly recommend that you don't use the conditional operator as a poor man's `if`, where both the true and false conditions are executed purely for their side effects. Either use `if`, or when (as in this case) you're assigning to a single variable in both cases, just use the conditional on the right-hand side of the assignment: `currentPlayer = currentPlayer === 1 ? 2 : 1;`

Comment: The main difference is that calling `addEventListener`, as the name suggests, keeps adding new event listeners. If you ran the first snippet twice for instance, both listeners get called and the variable is toggled two times. Assigning to `onclick` however overwrites the previous handler function, so having it two times will "work". My guess is you accidentally put that code in a place where it gets called repeatedly.

Comment: *"The 1st code only changed the activeplayer once in two clicks."* [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/9f3qycmd/), if I add the missing `)` and assume a `currentPlayer` variable is in the containing scope.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to attach the listener is to use `addEventListener`. This way gives you more control and also provided the event object as the first parameter in the event handler.

The [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick#Syntax) states the following:

> *Only one `onclick` handler can be assigned to an object at a time. You may prefer to use the `EventTarget.addEventListener()` method instead, since it's more flexible.*

Also, I would use 0 and 1 to represent player 1 and 2 respectively, because this reduces the logic for swapping to a simple arithmetic-based switch.

```js
var currentPlayer = 0; // Current player (global)

addEvent('.switchPlayer', 'click', handleSwitchPlayer);

/*
 * Switches the current player by toggling between 0 and 1.
 */
function handleSwitchPlayer(e) {
  currentPlayer = 1 - currentPlayer;
  console.log('Swapped to player #' + (currentPlayer + 1));
}

/**
 * Adds an event litener to element(s) by selector.
 */
function addEvent(elementOrSelector, eventName, eventHandler) {
  if (typeof elementOrSelector === 'string') {
    elementOrSelector = document.querySelectorAll(elementOrSelector);
    Array.from(elementOrSelector).forEach(element => {
      element.addEventListener(eventName, eventHandler);
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="switchPlayer">Switch player</button>
<button class="switchPlayer">Also switches player</button>
```